# Insert record into table in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012

I need to insert `PRDate` into `udEmp` table base on `PRCo`, `Employee` and `Job`. I have two parameters `@BegDate` and `@EndDate`, so for example the original record from the table like

```
@BegDate '07/27/2014'
@EndDate '08/10/2014'


select Co, Job, Employee 
from udEmp
```

[image]

I need some code to get the result like this

[image]

The `PRDate` will be sunday start from `BegDate` and end in `EndDate`. I think cursor may can do it, how I could not figure out. Please help. Thank

Comment: What database are you using? Please tag the question appropriately.  You have enough points on Stack Overflow that you should know this already.

Comment: the database i am using is sqlsever 2012

Comment: Next time can you add the tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a cursor.  A simple recursive CTE solves the problem:

```
with dates as (
      select cast(@BegDate as date) as thedate
      union all
      select dateadd(day, 7, thedate)
      from dates
      where thedate < @EndDate
     )
select e.Co, e.Job, e.Employee, dates.thedate as prdate
from udemp e cross join
     dates;
```

This is easy enough to adapt to an `insert` if that is what you really need.